# After form post form is submitted, how to send message to html/javascript if file can only be accessed through post? post request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to make my registration form show a message, on the same page as the registration form, that a username is taken if it is taken after the form is submitted.

I made a registration form that posts input to the file add-user.php. inside my add-user.php file I have two functions. ->nameTaken functions checks if a username is already in the database, and ->insert inserts names into a database if they are not taken. This file can only be accessed through a post request or else I get 500 server errors and errors that its values are null, see my routes below.

here is the add-user.php file code :

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/javascript');

$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if(!$app['database']->nameTaken($_POST['username'])){

    $app['database']->insert('users', [

        'name' => $_POST['username'],

        'password' => $hash

    ]);
};
```

here is the nameTaken function that is in another file :

```
 public function nameTaken($username){

        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE name = :name');

        $statement->execute(array('name' => $username));

        $res = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $exists = array_pop($res);

        if ($exists > 0) {

            $json = array(
                'success' => false
            );

            echo json_encode($json);

            return true;

        } else {
            //the name can be made
            $json = array(
                'success' => true
            );

            echo json_encode($json);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is working properly, but I don't know how to send this information to my html when I'm redirected back to the file with my form, so that it can show a message if a registration was succesful or if it failed because the username is aready taken.

I tried making a json output for this and getting it with a promise, but immediately after the form was submitted I'm redirected to my form page and the ajax call is null. I've only seen questions for how to do this while the username/password is being typed into the registration form on here, but I want to show the message after the registration form is submitted. How would I do this?

my promise ajax request to the php post file :

```
window.onload = function(){

    function get(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
          xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
          xhr.send();
        });
      }

    document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', () => {
            let promise = get('/controllers/contact.php').then((name) => {
            console.log(name);
        });
    });
}
```

I can't use this javascript because it executes before the php file is loaded, and then after the php file loads and I'm redirected to the page with my form, everything in the php file is erased, and my promise ajax request has already been executed.

my html :

```
<form method='POST' action='/users' id='register'>

            Username<input type='text' name='username' required>

            Password<input type='password' name='password' required>

            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>

        </form>
```

These are the errors I'm getting in my server

```
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:07 2018] 127.0.0.1:36690 [200]: /
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:07 2018] 127.0.0.1:36694 [200]: /registerFail.js
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:10 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 5
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: app in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36734 [500]: /controllers/add-user.php - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nameTaken() on null in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/imagePoster/controllers/add-user.php on line 7
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36738 [302]: /users
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36744 [200]: /
[Thu Aug 16 17:38:11 2018] 127.0.0.1:36750 [200]: /registerFail.js
```

First I'm on the main '/' page. Immediately when I submit my form, the ajax request runs before the php file is loaded and so everything is undefined, then when my php file loads and checks for the username, everything works fine and the username is either reject or put into my database. Then I'm redirected back to the the '/' directory with my form. I can't show an error message because the ajax executes before the php file is loading and I don't know how to fix this. I want to show the error message when I'm redirected back to the form page after the file has loaded. What would the code look like for me to do this?

```
<?php

$router->get('', 'controllers/index.php');

$router->get('about', 'controllers/about.php');

$router->get('contact', 'controllers/contact.php');

$router->post('users', 'controllers/add-user.php');

$router->post('login', 'controllers/login.php');
```

This is my router. controllers/add-user.php does not exist unless I make a post request to it. The other places, I can just type in a url and go to them.

I see this on many websites with a registration, submitting a form and then the page reloads to show if a password/username is taken or incorrect, and I'd appreciate if anyone can show me a link or guide me to anywhere on how this is usually done. I have found this link on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXIIWVR1PLk , but in the video this users route links can be accessed with get requests directly in the url. The page that handles if a username is taken or not for me can only be accessed through a post request, and then it is removed from access without another post request, I can not get it or else I get a 500 server error and other null variable errors. And other plaes I've just seen how to show an error message while the user is typing in a password/username, instead of after a form submission which is what I want.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You need to prevent the default submit event if you want to submit the form asynchronously. The idea is that you would post the form using your XMLHttpRequest object, and redirect (using window.location) if the submission was successful.

Comment: Just adding that when you make an ajax call, what ever you send back from php will be the response that ajax receives. In that way you can send from php the ok or error status that your javascript will need for futher actions.

Comment: What does the code for that look like? I've been told to do that before with this same problem and nothing worked and I'm not sure if I made the code correctly. @TiesonT.

Comment: @juan the php file is loading after the ajax call is made so the ajax call comes up with 500 server error/undefined errors.

Comment: Something like this would work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Using_XMLHttpRequest_and_the_FormData_object

Comment: If you want to make your life easier and you don't have issues using jQuery I suggest you use jQuery's ajax. It makes ajax really easy.

Answer (score 0):

modify your current php and add this else statement.

```
if(!$app['database']->nameTaken($_POST['username'])){
    $app['database']->insert('users', [
        'name' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $hash
    ]);
} else {
    $_SESSION["error_msg"] = "That Username belongs to someone else."
}
```

Somewhere in your html paste this.

```
<?php if (array_key_exists("error_msg", $_SESSION)){
    echo $_SESSION["error_msg"];
}
```